# Why interval of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was wondering why the interval of convergence of a real, one variable power series needs to be an interval. Any deep reason, or elementary way to see it?

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward consequence of the comparison test for convergence, and that test is pretty intuitive.

Comment: If the series $\sum_n a_nx^n$ converges absolutely for $x=a$, then, since $|x^n|=|x|^n$, for all $0\leq b<a$ you also have absolute convergence. So, the place where it converges absolutely is an interval. Comparison test alone **doesn't** tell you about just convergence (since it is only applicable to positive series), but, if $a_nx^n$ doesn't tend to zero for some positive $x=a$, then it also doesn't tend to zero for $|x|=b$ for all $a<b$. So, the place where the terms don't tend to zero is the complement of an interval. Finally, you can show that the boundary of both regions coincide.

Comment: That both boundaries coincide can be done with a single computation of the supremum of those geometric series bounding the series of absolute values. That gives you [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) formula. Incidentally, the same value tells you the infimum of the values of $|x|$ for which $|a_nx^n|$ doesn't tend to zero.

Comment: "but, if $a_n x^n$ doesn't tend to zero for some positive $x=a$, then it also doesn't tend to zero for $|x|=b$ for all $a\lt b$. So, the place where the terms don't tend to zero is the complement of an interval" There's a typo here somewhere, right?